# How to use mutt to send me notification when program is finished

Tags: linux, shell, email, terminal, mutt

I am using Linux. I want the computer send me an email when the program is finished by using `mutt` (the school does not allow us to use `mail`). **I tried `mutt` and it works fine.**

I use following shell script to run program

`cd /home/program/K_10 && nohup Rscript program_1.R> program_1_out.txt;`

How can I make it to send me an email when the program is finished. The email should have
`The job /home/program/K_10/program_1.R is finished`. Also, if it is possible, can you help me to attach `/home/program/K_10/program_1.txt`, which is the results of `program_1.R`?
I am quite new about Linux.

Comment: The way you send mail is normally using the `mail` command. Are you saying that you are not permitted to use the `mail` command, but you want to send mail anyway? (Mutt is an MUA and does not deliver mail.)

Comment: @GregHewgill You are right. The IT guys told me I can only use `mutt`.

Comment: @GregHewgill I think `mutt` can send mail.

Comment: Yes, mutt provides a user interface to send mail. But being an MUA, it calls another process to actually *deliver* the mail (usually `mail` or `sendmail`). Mutt itself does not deliver mail.

Comment: @GregHewgill. This is what IT said "The campus machines are not configured to act and mail servers, so the mail application will not work. You could use the mutt in its place." And I use `mutt`, it works fine (it can send email and receive email).

Comment: Try sending an email with mutt: `mutt "your@email" -s "Test" < /dev/null"`; if it works, mutt is well configured on your machine.

Comment: @Juancho. Thanks. I tried it and it works now. Can you tell how to send email when the program is finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is something like this:

```
cd /home/program/K_10 && nohup Rscript program_1.R> program_1_out.txt;
echo "The job /home/program/K_10/program_1.R is finished" |mutt "your@email" -s "Your job"
```

that is, in a script first execute the job, and then (in sequence) send mail to yourself.  The `echo` command pipes into `mutt` which uses it as the content of the mail.  The `-s` option sets the *subject* of the mail.

A nicer way to do this would be to put the gist of the commands into a *script*, something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $(dirname $1) && nohup Rscript $(basename $1) > $(basename $1 .R)_out.txt;
echo "The job $1 is finished" |mutt "your@email" -s "Your job"
```

and (calling that file `run-job`), invoke it by

```
run-job /home/program/K_10/program_1.R
```

Breaking it down a little:

- `run-job` is named to hint at the *function* of the script.  Script names do not have a set convention (it is up to the developer).  Some use a `".sh"` suffix on the names to make their type more apparent, but it is not essential.
- The `".R"` suffix is another naming convention, but may be needed by `Rscript`.  In any case, it is part of the existing filename.
- `$1` is the *parameter* (or *argument*) given to the script.   A more complete script might check (a) if the parameter is present and (b) if the parameter corresponds to an existing file, but those steps are omitted to keep it simple.
- The `$(dirname $1)` returns `/home/program/K_10`, and
- The `$(basename $1 .R)` takes that `/home/program/K_10/program_1.R` and returns `program_1`.
- For this simple script, it is possible to take the parts of a pathname and use them to make a more general script than using just the literal commands.

The `nohup` is awkward here; I would move it out of the script.  Then you could control directly the way the script was run, e.g.,

```
nohup run-job /home/program/K_10/program_1.R &
```

When creating a script such as `run-job`, you should remember to do this:

- make it executable, e.g., `chmod u+x run-job`
- either put the script into a directory on your `$PATH` (such as `$HOME/bin` on many systems), or take care to invoke it using its path. For instance, if it is in the current directory, you could simply do

  `nohup ./run-job /home/program/K_10/program_1.R &`
- For isolating problems (either my typo, or some other reason), the shell provides a *trace* feature (the actual commands will be printed as they are run).  To turn on tracing, change the first line of the script to

  `#!/bin/sh -x`

Comment: I put `run-job.sh` in the folder same as `program_1.R`. But it still does not work. Maybe the computer of campus doe not allow me to edit bash file.

Comment: But what does the script *do*?  (gotta go for now though).

Comment: I usually put `cd /home/program/K_10 && nohup Rscript program_1.R> program_1_out.txt` in `program_1.sh`. And I type `./program_1.sh`. Then, it will run.